# add a column to a data.frame after melt an array

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame` that I got after `melt` a array, which would mean a matrix 3 dimensional with values of a variable over a region during `12 months` `[48,38,12]==[longitude, latitude, time]`. So, when I melt the matrix, my data would be something like:

```
        lon lat date    value
        1   1   1    1 18.00000
        2   2   1    1 17.83333
        3   3   1    1 18.83333
        4   4   1    1 20.50000
```

Now, I wanted to have in the column date the values as a `Date` , I mean `"1986-01-01" "1986-02-01" "1986-03-01" "1986-04-01"`..is that possible? Is there an easy way to do that??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   df <- read.table(header=T, text = "
   lon lat date    value
   1   1   1    1 18.00000
   2   2   1    1 17.83333
   3   3   1    1 18.83333
   4   4   1    1 20.50000")

   # Your melted data frame
   df
   #   lon lat date    value
   # 1   1   1    1 18.00000
   # 2   2   1    1 17.83333
   # 3   3   1    1 18.83333
   # 4   4   1    1 20.50000

   df$Dates <- seq(as.Date("1986-01-01"), by = "month", length.out = 4)
   df
   #   lon lat date    value      Dates
   # 1   1   1    1 18.00000 1986-01-01
   # 2   2   1    1 17.83333 1986-02-01
   # 3   3   1    1 18.83333 1986-03-01
   # 4   4   1    1 20.50000 1986-04-01
```

Comment: OK, that's what I wanted, easier than expected :)  thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

We can use `seq`

```
seq(as.Date("1986-01-01"), length.out = nrow(dat), by = "1 month")
#[1] "1986-01-01" "1986-02-01" "1986-03-01" "1986-04-01"
```

Or as @Frank mentioned in the comments, if this is based on the 'date' column

```
seq(as.Date("1986-01-01"), length.out = 12, by = "1 month")[dat$date]
```

Comment: Assuming the OP's dates cover 12 months like 1..12 (as seems likely), they can do `seq(as.Date("1986-01-01"), length.out = 12, by = "1 month")[dat$date]`, I guess.

Comment: @Frank  the comment Can you explain this? Oh I got it..sorry..thank you. :)

Comment: @SowmyaS.Manian  Thank you , plus one to you as well